# sse precision error with Matrix multiplication

Tags: c, sse, precision, matrix-multiplication, rounding-error

My program does NxN matrices multiplication where elements of both the matrices are initialized to values (0, 1, 2, ... N) using a for loop. Both the matrix elements are of type float. There is no memory allocation problem. Matrix sizes are input as a multiple of 4 eg: 4x4 or 8x8 etc. The answers are verified with a sequential calculation. Everything works fine upto matrix size of 64x64. A difference between the sequential version and SSE version is observed only when the matrix size exceeds 64 (eg: 68 x 68).

SSE snippet is as shown  (size = 68):

`void matrix_mult_sse(int size, float *mat1_in, float *mat2_in, float *ans_out) {
    __m128 a_line, b_line, r_line;
    int i, j, k;
    for (k = 0; k < size * size; k += size) {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i += 4) {
            j = 0;
            b_line = _mm_load_ps(&mat2_in[i]);
            a_line = _mm_set1_ps(mat1_in[j + k]);
            r_line = _mm_mul_ps(a_line, b_line);
            for (j = 1; j < size; j++) {
                b_line = _mm_load_ps(&mat2_in[j * size + i]);
                a_line = _mm_set1_ps(mat1_in[j + k]);
                r_line = _mm_add_ps(_mm_mul_ps(a_line, b_line), r_line);
            }
            _mm_store_ps(&ans_out[i + k], r_line);
        }
    }
}`

With this, the answer differs at element 3673 where I get the answers of multiplication as follows

**scalar**: 576030144.000000 &  **SSE**: 576030208.000000

I also wrote a similar program in Java with the same initialization and setup and N = 68 and for element 3673, I got the answer as 576030210.000000

Now there are three different answers and I'm not sure how to proceed. Why does this difference occur and how do we eliminate this?

Comment: So long as the results are accurate to around 6 significant digits then there is nothing to worry about - this is single precision floating point after all.

Comment: But its not the decimal part which loses precision. It its Integer part.

Comment: You get around 6 *significant digits* regardless of where the decimal point is - this is how floating point works. I suggest reading http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html before you go too much further with writing floating point code.

Comment: @Jagruth.P, Is the code compiled in 32-bit or 64-bit mode?  If it's 32-bit code then the compiler may be using x87 code which will do internal calculations with 80-bits and then round back to float.  You could look at the assembly or write your scalar code using SSE (e.g. using `mm_add_ss`) to make sure you're using the same hardware.

Comment: @Z boson - I was using a 32 bit ubuntu image running on Oracle Virtual Box (My laptop is 64 bit though). Im not sure in what way virtual Ubuntu affects this, but strangely when I ran the same thing on a properly boot partitioned Ubuntu, the code ran smoothly with no errors and I even got the sequential and SSE part as the same (meaning no precision difference was observed).

Comment: @PaulR - Yes I can see what you meant. When I executed the program declaring all the fields as **int**, I got a different answer than what I got when all the fields were **float**. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am summarizing the discussion in order to close this question as answered.

So according to the article (What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic) in  [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), floating point always results in a *rounding error* which is a direct consequence of the approximate representation nature of the floating point number.

Arithmetic operations such as addition, subtraction etc results in a precision error. Hence, the ***6 most significant digits*** of the floating point answer (irrespective of where the decimal point is situated) can be considered to be accurate while the other digits may be erroneous (prone to precision error).